# grails elasticsearch only indexed one instance out of many

Tags: grails, elasticsearch

I am using the elasticsearch grails plugin for the first time, and when I set the config bulkIndexOnStartup = true, it indexed several of the domain classes correctly, but for a couple of others it seemed to only index one instance out of many, even though I saw 99 distinct instances in the database.

When I tried to specifically index the instances by calling

```
elasticSearchService.index( anInstance )
```

it would just delete the old entry and add a new one, so at the end there was still only one instance in elasticsearch. Is there an "indexAllDistinct" setting somewhere? How does it decide to add a new entry or replace an existing entry?

I also noticed that on the instances that were indexed correctly, the _id fields all had numeric values, but on the incorrectly indexed instance, the _id field was "null".

EDIT: I found that the incorrectly indexed classes have the "id" mapping name set to a different field. How can I tell elasticsearch that the "id" has a different name for these classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For grails domain classes that map the default "id" to another name, I had to add a transient "id" for elasticsearch. For example:

```
class LogEntry {
  Integer logId // replaces default id
  ...

  static mapping = {
    id name: 'logId', column: 'LOG_ID'
    ...
  }

  static transients = ['id'] // for elasticsearch
  def getId(){
    return logId
  }
}
```